# Android: placing an ImageView on an exact location on the screen

Tags: android, imageview, location

I would like to use `getLocationOnScreen` to get the location of an ImageView, and then I would like to place another ImageView exactly at that place.

Assume they both are in the same layout. When the app starts only `imgv1` is visible. The user can move and rotate that image. Then the user can press a button and second image, `imgv2` should be placed exactly on top of `imgv1` so it covers it. Both `imgv1` and `imgv2` have the same size.

For example, assume I have `imgv1` and `imgv2` as:

```
ImageView imgv1, imgv2;

int[] img_coordinates = new int[2];
imgv1.getLocationOnScreen(img_coordinates);
```

I wanted to use something like:

```
imgv2.setX(img_coordinates[0]);
imgv2.setY(img_coordinates[2]);
```

but this doesn't do what I need to do, which is to place the top left corner of `imgv2` on the top left corner of `imgv1`.

Any other method that helps me to do so is fine too.

** Update **

This is the layout I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/tools_root"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/transparent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgv1"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:cameraCropOutput="true"
    app:cameraPlaySounds="false" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgv2"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:visibility="gone" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Do you want to animate imgv2 to place of  imgv1? Are these images in the same layout file or added dynamically? Do these image views have same width and height? Are you looking for Activity/Fragment transitions? Or Scene Transitions?

Comment: No I don't need animation. The images have same size.

Comment: Are these images in the same layout file or added dynamically? Looks like you can just change the visibility of imgv2 and place it on top of imgv1 in xml file.

Comment: Assume one is in  a layout file. Then user can move and rotate that to any location s/he wants. Then by pressing a button a second image dynamically will appear and shall be placed on exactly same location.

Comment: @pskink can you please elaborate in an answer? I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The javadoc for view says that setX and setY will offsett the image from it's original location.  It looks like what you want to use is setLeft and setTop.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setleft

Answer (score 0):

If i have overlapping views I generally put them in layout and show/hide them. However if you want to dit via code try setting layout params of second image like:

lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT, image1.getId());

lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_TOP, image1.getId());

...something like it.
Positioning depends a lot on parent of Image views. Relative Layout would be correct choice.

Answer (score 0):

Step #1: Put `imgv1` in a `FrameLayout`

Step #2: Put `imgv2` in that same `FrameLayout`, with `android:visibility="gone"`

Step #3: When the user presses the button, call `imgv2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)`

```
<FrameLayout android:id="combined">
  <ImageView android:id="imgv1" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" />
  <ImageView android:id="imgv2" android:visibility="gone" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"  />
</FrameLayout>
```

Missing are sizing/positioning rules for the `FrameLayout`, which would be whatever you are presently using for your starting conditions for `imgv1`, presumably.

---

Alternatively, have one `ImageView`, rather than two, and change the image on the button click. For example, you could use a `LayerDrawable` (or the equivalent resource) to layer two drawables on top of each other, and show that.

Comment: Thanks. But user can move the `imgv1`, so how to I know where to put `imgv2`?

Comment: @TJ1: "But user can move the imgv1" -- adjust your code to move the `FrameLayout`. "so how to I know where to put imgv2" -- it follows along with the `FrameLayout`.

Comment: can you please provide some code? I am not getting it :(

Comment: @TJ1: see updated answer, which is more or less what you have added to your question, except that I am uncertain why `imgv1` is marked as `gone`.

Comment: Thanks for the update, but after a user moves the imgv1 with a finger on the screen, how imgv2 would now where it should go?

Comment: @TJ1: The user is incapable of moving an `ImageView` on the screen, unless you write code to do so. It's not like `ImageView` magically can be moved. Instead, presumably you are using touch events and are moving the `ImageView`. So, as I wrote, you change your code to move the `FrameLayout`. Other than changing which `View` you are using for your update-the-position methods, I would not expect there to be many other changes required.

Comment: @pskink: That would be another possibility. Personally, off the cuff, I'd go with the replace-the-image approach, particularly if you don't need an animated transition between showing one image versus both images. Tough to beat a single `setImageResource()` call for simplicity. :-)